# How to Calculate Weeks of Cover per product on existing inventory Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following

[image: Excel Data Sample]

I am currently receiving. I'd like to calculate how many weeks of cover I have based on the average sales of the two weeks prior. I'd like it to be reoccurring so I'm not constantly having to change it. Is there an easy way to do this in Excel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste this formula in a cell in row 2 and copy down from there.

```
=ROUND($D2/IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($C$1:$C1,$B$1:$B1,$B2,$A$1:$A1,">"&$A2-3),$C2),0)
```

Observe that it takes the average from the cells above the row it is in, meaning the past 2 weeks, excluding the current one. But if there is no data, as is the case in row 1, the sales number from the current row will be used, and if that is zero a #DIV/0 error will result. Such an error will also be returned if there have been no sales in the past 2 weeks. You may have to tweak the formula if this is a problem.

The inventory on hand is then divided into the average determined in the above way. My formula uses the ROUND() function to return an integer.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Place this formula into the week 4 cell for product BA1 (assuming your table starts in cell A1)
   `=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,B:B,B8,A:A,">"&A8-3,A:A,"<"&A8)`
2. Drag down the formula going forwards
3. Next year, begin again